# Can't get to AWS Lambda web console, chunk missing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I periodically get this error when I log into the web console to access the Lambda page:

[image: error message]

I've tried chrome and edge, same error.

Lambda is the only service I've experienced this with and I can't access Lambda sometimes for days when this happens.

The full error text:

An error occurred.
Loading chunk 3 failed. (error: [https://a.b.cdn.console.awsstatic.com/a/v1/5FXOMULGD57QCWU3UFDWBUBS5D6YOLCW6N5I2MXHOPQGVG55V6DQ/vendors~app~main.js](https://a.b.cdn.console.awsstatic.com/a/v1/5FXOMULGD57QCWU3UFDWBUBS5D6YOLCW6N5I2MXHOPQGVG55V6DQ/vendors%7Eapp%7Emain.js))

Comment: you are hiding the error message. show the error message so that we can figure out what causing it

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan the rest of the error text has been added to the original now.

Comment: do you have antivirus running in your laptop/PC?

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan yeah, it's running AV software.

Comment: Turn off your antivirus and try again

Comment: The issue went away on it's own but I had opened an incident with AWS and they suggested something similar. I can't disable the AV on my corp laptop so I'll have to get with security next time this happens... thanks